# Printing two DIN A6 pages on a A4 sheet without border in order 1,2,1,2

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript

I have created a postcard in DIN A6 format which I want to print with a A4 printer.

To do that I need to place the two pages (1=front and 2=back) on the A4 page in the following order: 1,2,1,2. It allows to print the A4 sheet on both sides and receive four copies of the postcard after cutting.

```
+---------+---------+
|  front  |  back   |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
|  front  |  back   |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

The source PDF was created with OpenOffice.org Draw and has the correct page size of DIN A6 (=exactly the size of ¼ of A4) in its metadata. Thus the pages don't need to be scaled. I do not want any additional borders between the pages.

Any solution that will work with software available packaged for Ubuntu Linux is appreciated! Ghostscript is only in the tags because I guess it would be the software of choice although I don't get on with its command line syntax:(

Answer (score 0):

Look at these answers, and you'll learn how to approach this problem:

- [Linux-based tool to chop PDFs into multiple pages](https://superuser.com/a/192293/40894)
- [Freeware to split a pdf's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894)