# PDF reverse n-up

Tags: linux, pdf

There are several tools that can n-up pdfs, like pdfjam, pdftk,...

How would I reverse the process, say, make a document of 2n pages from a document of n-pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answers will help you:

- [Split one PDF page into two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521648/359307)
- [Linux-based tool to chop PDFs into multiple pages](https://superuser.com/a/192293/40894)
- [Freeware to split a pdf's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894)

They show how to use sophisticated Ghostscript command line parameters to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Great! That's what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If using a Java or .Net library is ok for you, you can use iText / iTextSharp.

An example for tiling an existing document can be found in the book iText in Action, 2nd edition, in the freely available [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf): [TilingHero.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=116) / [TilingHero.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=TilingHero).

Otherwise [PDF Scissors](http://www.pdfscissors.com/) might be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Krop (Python) & PDFscissors (Java) haven't been mentioned yet:

http://arminstraub.com/software/krop

https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/

[I crossposted these on the other threads too make it simple to find..]

Answer (score -2):

Here is one of the possibilities. You can use pdftk multiple times to get the desired result.

1) Use pdftk to segregate your document into single page files.

```
 pdftk largefile.pdf burst
```

2) Merge the small files thus created in step 1 as per your requirement.

I know it is a clumsy process but should work for you.

EDIT: Please have a look at this project

http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/

It can solve your issue. (you can find the whole thread here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1665621)

Comment: This would not make 2 pages from 1, would it?

Comment: It will separate 2 page document into 2 separate 1 page files. In general, If there are 2n pages in your original, this will create 2n separate 1 page files. Then you can stitch relevant pages together.

Comment: @maths-help-seeker: you didn't "get" the problem of Jo So. He wants to split individual pages into multiple... (These files were once created to "save paper", in order to print 2 original pages onto one sheet of paper).

Comment: please see my edit. It should work for his case.