# Chop pages of a PDFs horizontally WITH overlap

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I want to convert a pdf file so that each page is cut horizontally into two pieces, with some overlap. My machine is mac and I'm now using mutool with the following command:

```
mutool poster -y 2 in.pdf out.pdf
```

But this is not exactly what I want. Because each page is cut down in the middle, it's possible that some pages are cut exactly in the middle of a line, making it hard to read the last line of the first page and the first line of the second page.

E.g. here is an example page:

[image]

Mutool would split it into two pages, with the top half:

[image]

and bottom half:

[image]

But I want some overlapping margins so that the middle sentence is still readable, like this:

[image]

and

[image]

The closest thing I can find is to use ghostscript, like the one in this topic
[Chop pages of a PDFs into multiple pages](https://superuser.com/questions/191373/chop-pages-of-a-pdfs-into-multiple-pages)

But I'm no programmer and I don't know how to make ghostscript work for this situation. Please help!

(I understand there's another tool called `pdfposter`, but, like `mutool`, it has no option for overlapping margin.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an amazing graphical tool called [`krop`](http://arminstraub.com/software/krop) which I learned about [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/774212). There is a [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/krop) for it in Ubuntu 20.04, which is how I installed it.

`krop` is a super tool! It allows you to select any number of (possibly overlapping) regions to chop each page into, can automatically shrink a selection to remove the surrounding whitespace, and can crop differentially for even and odd pages.

Best of all, it has a built in option to split the selected area into equally sized (overlapping) pieces for reading on a 4:3 ebook screen, which was precisely my intended application for chopping-with-overlap (and is perhaps yours too...)!