# How do I 'unbook' a pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, pdftk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a PDF's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/questions/235074/how-can-i-split-a-pdfs-pages-down-the-middle)

I have a pdf file that was made into a booklet format. It is meant to print on A4 paper in landscape orientation; here are two pages in the pdf, which should correspond to four pages in the actual book.

```
 -------------------------------
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|    (1)       |      (3)       |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              |                |
 ------------------------------- 

 -------------------------------
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|    (4)       |      (2)       |
|              |                |
|              |                |
|              |                |
 -------------------------------
```

The bracketed numbers correspond to the order of the individual pages.

I know that there are all sorts of commands (pdfbook, pdfnup, etc.) on linux (which was probably used to make this booklet in the first place). How do I 'unbook' it---that is, I'd like to make a pdf document from this where each individual page of the final product is an individual page of the pdf, ordered in the usual way.

Comment: Is your example layout above verbatim the layout of your book? How would you even put that together? If it was a different layout I might have a solution, but I'm confused the way it is currently.

Comment: as mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/235327/35237), use BRISS

Answer (score 1):

You should look at these answers:

- [**Convert PDF 2 sides per page to 1 side per page**](https://superuser.com/a/189109/40894).
- [**Freeware to split a pdf's pages down the middle?**](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894).

They do not apply exactly and *literally* to your question. But if you study them, you'll very easily figure out how to modify the method described there in order to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is generally considered a `one-way` format only. If the page flow is mangled it would probably be very hard to get meaningful results. Better try to find the original pre-press version of the original file that was used to make the PDF. Converting PDF can be done but in most cases it badly affects the end result. **[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)** is a free tool that does PDF to HTML,RTF,EPUB,etc but results vary. The app that gave the best results for me was `SolidPDFConverter` but it is commercial.