# Is there a command-line method to split a gigantic single-page PDF file into one file with multiple pages?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, pdf

How can I split (tile?) one huge PDF onto multiple pages? The result should be one PDF with multiple A4 pages or several A4 PDFs.

I'm not looking for a solution specific to this method of generating the problem: the input PDF has been generated by Graphviz `dot`, eg. `dot -Tpdf sample.dot > sample.pdf`. When I did not add a `size="8,11"; ratio="fill";` to the graph the output PDF is very large. If I add the size/fill-hints `dot` only scaled things down for me.

Lets give you one example, if my original PDF was huge like this:

```
+-------------------+
|                   |
|  O                |
|  :                |
|  :..........C     |
|  :        :       |
|  :        :       |
|  :        :       |
|  :        G       |
|  :        :       |
|  :        :       |
|  :        :       |
|  :        :       |
|  U        :       |
|           B       |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

This should be split by a command like

```
pdftile sample.pdf -x 2 -y 3 > sample-2x3.pdf
```

into

```
+---------+---------+
|         |         |
|  O      |         |
|  :      |         |
|  :......|...C     |
|  :      | :       |
+---------+---------+
|  :      | :       |
|  :      | :       |
|  :      | G       |
|  :      | :       |
|  :      | :       |
+---------+---------+
|  :      | :       |
|  :      | :       |
|  U      | :       |
|         | B       |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/54054 and duplicate candidates.

Comment: I've updated this question to differentiate it from https://superuser.com/q/827462/11116

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like [pdfposter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pdfposter.1.html) can do this.

Comment: Yeah, it promises to do that, but it does not work :-(

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: pdfposter appears to be broken for some people. See [this bug report](https://gitlab.com/pdftools/pdfposter/issues/2) for a workaround.

Comment: Exacrtly what I was looking for, I have a large ERD diagram PDF file generated with rails-erd and graphviz, I could turn into a multiple pages file. `pdfposter -p2x999a4` gave me 22 pages, `-p999x2a4` 44 pages

Answer (score 7):

Actually `mutool` has almost the same syntax as the one you're suggesting (are you its author ??) :

```
mutool -x 2 -y 3 sample.pdf sample-2x3.pdf
```

To install `mutool`, just install [`mupdf`](http://www.mupdf.com), which is probably packaged with most GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: worked like a dream to break my A0 poster down to A3 versions for draft printing.

Comment: Thank you, did the job in 5 minutes (the package name was mupdf-tools for me).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the tools already mentioned, there is also a tool I wrote because I was unhappy with pdfposter (no overlap between pages for gluing) and wanted more control over the output. The primary interface to the tool is a GUI but it also has a CLI interface that will let you do the same things from the command line. You can grab it here:

https://pypi.org/project/plakativ/

If you are on Linux you can install it with pip. Windows executables are also regularly built on [AppVeyor CI](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/josch/plakativ/build/artifacts) or are available with each release: https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/plakativ/releases

[image: plakativ]

Comment: Awesome! worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on http://www.graphviz.org/doc/FAQ.html:
Q14. How can I print a big graph on multiple pages?

The page attribute, if set, tells Graphviz to print the graph as an array of pages of the given size. Thus, the graph

digraph G {
  page="8.5,11";
  ...
}

will be emitted as 8.5 by 11 inch pages. When printed, the pages can be tiled to make a drawing of the entire graph. At present, the feature only works with PostScript output.
Alternatively, there are various tools and viewers which will take a large picture and allow you to extract page-size pieces, which can then be printed.

ONLY Postscript! But for automation no showstopper :-).
Just let ps2pdf run over it. It worked for me.

Comment: link is https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqMultiPage

Answer (score 1):

Several linux utilities come to mind:

(from their man pages)

**pdfseperate [*options*] INPUT.PDF OUTPUT%d.PDF**

reads INPUT.PDF, extracts one or more pages, and writes one PDF file for each page to OUTPUT%d.PDF (%d is placeholder for page number) (from 'poppler-utils' package)

**pdftk INPUT.PDF burst**

reads INPUT.PDF, producing one or more PDF files containing individual pages, named 'pg-XXXX.pdf' (unless output filename specified) (from 'pdftk' package)

Comment: these utilities seperate multi-page pdfs into single-page pdfs, this is a single gigantic page pdf. This would be a good answer for this question, if it wasn't already answered: https://superuser.com/a/997424/11116

Answer (score 0):

As yet another alternative, you can use the cross platform CLI tool [pdftilecut](https://github.com/oxplot/pdftilecut) which I authored a while ago, to split PDF pages into tiles with trim lines and grid references for easy assembly should you want to print them:

```sh
pdftilecut -tile-size A4 -in sample.pdf -out sample-tiled.pdf
```