# Converting a multi-sheet per page pdf to single sheet per page

Tags: pdf

My father-in-law usually creates his newsletters pre-'booked' -- that is, two columns with the pages in the right place such that you can print and staple the newsletter.  Unfortunately, this month we're using a printer that wants an un-booked PDF -- with one page per page, in the right order.  I can re-order pages easily enough, but is there any way to take a PDF which is essentially 2-up and split the pages?

Comment: What application did you use to generate the pdf? InDesign? It's in the app you used that you'd specify the print configuration (2-up for booklet, newsletter, etc.). Just change the print config to single page output and regenerate the pdf.

Comment: @burrowsrjl The booklet was generated using LibreOffice, but by putting two columns on each page so it folds nicely without setting any print config -- not my set-up :).

Answer (score 1):

for both raster and vector pdf content you can use this my script I named **decutshuffler**

**usage:**

> **decutshuffler filename.pdf**

- http://ge.tt/5IFrNiR/v/8

```
#!/bin/bash
#a script that takes a 2-up booklet, cut in half the two halves, mix together one by one the pages from odd and even resulting pdf and finally reorder pages in sequential order
filename=$1
w="$(pdfinfo $filename | grep "Page size" | cut -d x -f1 | tr 'Page size:' ' ' | xargs)"
h="$(pdfinfo $filename | grep "Page size" | cut -d x -f2  | tr 'pts' ' ' | xargs)"
halfw="`echo "scale=0; $w / 2" | bc -l`"
pages="`pdftk $filename dump_data output |grep Pages|cut -f2 -d :`"
sed -e "s/$w $h/$halfw $h/g"<$filename>even.pdf
sed -e "s/0 0 $w $h/$w 0 $halfw $h/g"<$filename>odd.pdf
rule="$(for i in `seq 1 $pages`; do echo -n "A$i B$i "; done)"
pdftk A=even.pdf B=odd.pdf cat $rule output interleaved.pdf
doubled="`echo "scale=0; $pages * 2" | bc -l`"
pages4="`echo "scale=0; $doubled / 2" | bc -l`"
deshuf="$(for ((x=$doubled, y=1;x>=$pages4, y<=$pages4;x--, y++)); do echo "$x $y "; done |awk '{ print ; getline ; print $2, $1 }' | tr ' ' '\n' | cat -b | sort -n +1 -2| cut -f1 | tr '\n' ' '| xargs)"
pdftk interleaved.pdf cat $deshuf output deshuffled.pdf
pdftk deshuffled.pdf output fixed.pdf && mv fixed.pdf deshuffled.pdf
echo "file created!"

echo $pages
echo $deshuf
echo "halfw is $halfw"

exit 0
```

this script

1. takes your pdf imposed as 2-up booklet as input

   - http://ge.tt/5IFrNiR/v/7
     [image: booklet animation]
2. split the source pdf into its two halves producing a file with odd pages and a file with even pages

   - http://ge.tt/5IFrNiR/v/4 (**odd.pdf**)
   - http://ge.tt/5IFrNiR/v/3 (**even.pdf**)
     [image: even pages animation]
     [image: odd pages animation]
3. mix **odd.pdf** and **even.pdf** together into one file, taking, alternately,  *page 1 from odd*, *page 1 from even*, *page 2 from odd*, *page 2 from even*... and so on...

   - http://ge.tt/5IFrNiR/v/5
4. finally, it with a special rule, reorders the file into sequential order, so pages, instead to be (for a 16 pages long booklet)

> **16 1 2 15 14 3 4 13 12 5 6 11 10 7 8 9**

are disposed **sequentially** in its natural order:

> **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16**

- http://ge.tt/5IFrNiR/v/6

Comment: Is there a general purpose solution that accepts ncols and nrows? I have 12x9=108 pages per sheet! Briss says image is too big. Here is the [zipped up PDF](http://www.sainsonic.com/skin/frontend/default/default/download/Manual/SainSonic-RST599-Manual.zip).

Comment: It seems like pdfcrop and [mutool poster](http://superuser.com/a/1039181/106115) is for the rescue.