# Is there a command-line method to split a multi-page PDF file into single pages?

Tags: macos, command-line, pdf

I have a single PDF file 6 pages long that I want to split into six seperate pdfs (1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf) such that each file produced represents one page from the input. I would love to be able to do this simple task from the command line.

Comment: A good command-line solution is from [this SE answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10509904/208704). You can install ghostscript using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: I've updated this question to differentiate it from https://superuser.com/q/437148/11116

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Open up the pdf in preview and then on the view menu select thumbnails. Ctrl select the pages that you want now drag and drop them to the desktop.

Comment: This worked well.  Took me about 30 seconds to do this after flailing about for around 30 minutes.  Some people are using this technique in conjunction w/ Automator but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 86):

This can be achieved by using `pdfseparate`. You can install poppler with homebrew, by `brew install poppler`. This will also install `pdfseparate`. To split the PDF `document.pdf` into into single pages `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, etc. use:

```
pdfseparate document.pdf %d.pdf
```

Comment: Just installed `poppler` a day ago for being able to convert PDF documents to SVG with [`pdf2svg`](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/). Didn't notice that `poppler` comes with `pdfseparate` command. Since the accepted answer above (dragging and dropping all PDF pages with preview to desktop) requires me to "click around" and since I like solutions on terminal that work automagically by just a single command line, `pdfseparate` is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for that hint!

Comment: Interestingly, pdfseparate produces pdfs whose total size is much much larger than the size of the original pdf. I had a 400 pages document with 1.9 MB. After splitting, I got something around 60 MB.

Comment: Just tested Konstantin's comment and he's right. Sizes from pdfseparate were ~9x bigger than those produced from just dragging pages out using preview.app

Comment: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=document-compressed.pdf document.pdf` both _before_ and _after_ splitting (i.e., then replace `document.pdf` by `1.pdf`, etc) helps to decrease the size (see also [Rastapopoulos's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1321515/splitting-pdf-files-using-pdfseparate-poppler)). Also it is expected to be bigger if some resources are shared among the pages, such as font inclusions.

Comment: Not sure if this is due to an update since the earlier comments, but I just split a 13 page PDF of scanned documents (created from an iPhone using Preview's Scan function) and the individual filesizes add up exactly to the original 13 page PDF as you would hope.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but mind that `brew install poppler` downloads the Internet.

Comment: `brew install poppler` is really too big just for doing a very simple job! Seems like it downloads and installs the whole Internet!

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in doing this from the command line, you can look at [Benjamin Han's splitPDF python script](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~benhdj/Mac/unix.html#splitPDF) to do the job. For instance:

```
splitPDF.py in.pdf 3 5
```

would split the file `in.pdf` into 3 files, splitting at pages 3 and 5.

Comment: This is good, and a bit more flexible in what you can output than pdfseparate above. Though it is mainly for splitting a pdf into chucks of pages, if you did want to split each page, you could easily use `seq` to produce a range of numbers in your command. Thanks!

Comment: something like `python splitPDF.py MyPDF.pdf $(seq -s ' ' 1 10 411)` worked for me

Comment: Words great. I confirm this works directly on MacOS 10.13.3

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu you'll need to install pdftk:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install pdftk
```

Then to have your problem solved, just:

```
pdftk input.pdf burst
```

Comment: As of 8/16/2023, this should be the accepted answer. With Nix, it even work without installing pdftk: `nix-shell -p pdftk --run 'pdftk multi_page.pdf burst'` (on Mac too).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract a range of pages, you can use the following script which you call like this (assumed that you save it to file pdfextract.py somewhere on your system's PATH, e.g. /usr/local/bin, and assign it execution permission with chmod 744 pdfextract.py):

pdfextract.py --file-in /path/to/large/pdf --file-out /path/to/new/pdf --start  --stop

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import argparse
import os
import subprocess as sp


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file-in', required=True, type=str, dest='file_in')
    parser.add_argument('--file-out', required=True, type=str, dest='file_out')
    parser.add_argument('--start', required=True, type=int, dest='start', default=-1)
    parser.add_argument('--stop', required=True, type=int, dest='stop', default=-1)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    assert os.path.isfile(args.file_in)
    assert not os.path.isfile(args.file_out)

    # remove temporary files
    for el in os.listdir('/tmp'):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/tmp', el)) and el[:12] == 'pdfseparate-':
            os.remove(os.path.join('/tmp', el))

    sp.check_call('pdfseparate -f {:d} -l {:d} {:s} /tmp/pdfseparate-%d.pdf'.format(args.start, args.stop, args.file_in), shell=True)

    cmd_unite = 'pdfunite '
    for i in range(args.start, args.stop + 1):
        cmd_unite += '/tmp/pdfseparate-{:d}.pdf '.format(i)
    cmd_unite += args.file_out
    sp.check_call(cmd_unite, shell=True)

    # remove temporary files
    for el in os.listdir('/tmp'):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/tmp', el)) and el[:12] == 'pdfseparate-':
            os.remove(os.path.join('/tmp', el))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have started to put together a [tool](https://github.com/lancejpollard/act) to provide a simplified interface to common actions.

You can split PDFs into individual pages like this:

```
$ npm install @lancejpollard/act -g
$ act split my.pdf -o outputDirectory
```

If nothing else check out the source and see how to write your own script to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Node.js script to achieve this (requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) to be installed):

```bash
# Customise this:
export PDFPATH=/path/to/input.pdf

npm install pdf-lib &&
cat << 'EOF' | node --input-type=module - "$PDFPATH"
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';

const pdfPath = process.argv[2];
const sourceDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await readFile(pdfPath))

for (let i = 0; i < sourceDoc.getPages().length; i++) {
  const outDoc = await PDFDocument.create()
  outDoc.addPage((await outDoc.copyPages(sourceDoc, [i]))[0])
  await writeFile(`${pdfPath}-${i}.pdf`, await outDoc.save());
}
EOF
```

**NOTE:** the script will create a `node_modules` directory in your CWD and install the `pdf-lib` dependency there.

Answer (score -1):

For another alternative, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025515/converting-a-multi-page-pdf-to-multiple-pages-using-a-single-command). This uses the [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) command line tools.

```
convert x.pdf -quality 100 -density 300x300 x-%04d.pdf
```

However, you have to be careful with the quality.

Comment: Because there are quality and density options, it sounds like this renders each page to an image. I think people here would prefer the option which preserves the original PDF data which might include text/fonts/vector graphics.