# Re-Order pages of an 'Unbooked' PDF - Batch / GhostScript / PDFtk

Tags: batch, pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

*Preamble: 'Unbooking' a PDF has been asked before. That said, I haven't found an answer to this specific part of the process. Thanks to extensive research and a lot of help from this site, I'm halfway there. Full explanation of what I'm doing and links to resources at the end of this question.*

---

**Primary Question**: (focus on this and ignore the rest, if you want)

I have, out of one "booked" PDF, managed to create 2 PDF files. One is the left side, and one is the right side of the original PDF. The left side's pages are in this order: `16, 2, 14, 4, 12, 6, 10, 8` and the right side's pages are in this order: `1, 15, 3, 13, 5, 11, 7, 9`.

I want to achieve normal single-page order (`1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 16`) in a ***single output file*** using any combination of `Batch`, `Ghostscript`, or `PDFtk`.

Using either PDFtk or GhostScript and likely some form of a batch for loop, I need to:

1. (maybe) Identify the total number of pages there are to work with(?)
2. Loop through them and compile an output file out of two documents in the correct order

---

**Further Question Detail & Testing Resources:**

A similar/partial solution may be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29601/how-do-i-unbook-a-pdf), however, I do not know python well enough to interpret what is happening or test it.

[Test_PageNumbers.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X76tfjhmt0GfMwoPJ-QZB15Ga8GqHaZk/view?usp=sharing) - Here's a link to an example "booked" PDF, what I'm starting with

*IMPORTANT NOTE -- The above is added for clarity. Splitting the above PDF is outside of the scope of this question and has been answered before. See bottom section of this question for details on that.*

[left-sections.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11YQ7Q_VH4DRS6-U4jn5Zkmqqto34kEut/view?usp=sharing) - Here's just the truncated left side to test with

[right-sections.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hT84zZg6dXfeErMHzLAkGy2JmpKpESUu/view?usp=sharing) - Here's just the truncated right side to test with

[DesiredOutput.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18YvQ-pHelUuTZO5LV7mWwY7SPy7PDcLw/view?usp=sharing) - Here's what the desired output would look like

Here's a table of what the correct order looks like:
[image: Table of Correct Order and Files]

---

**What I've Already Done**

This script combines the PDFs, but all out of order.

```
pdftk ^
  A=right-sections.pdf ^
  B=left-sections.pdf ^
  shuffle A B ^
  output single-pages-output.pdf
```

This script tells me the number of pages (outputs: `NumberOfPages: 8`) but I've had a terrible time isolating just the number using pure Batch script to use in a `for` loop, which is my preferred method so I can run this on multiple machines without an additional library install.

```
SET d=test
pdftk left-sections.pdf dump_data | findstr NumberOfPages>pgs
set /p d= < pgs
echo %d%
```

This was my attempt at isolating the number. It doesn't work yet. I don't know if this step is necessary. There may be another creative solution, perhaps with a `while` loop, looking at `errorlevel`?

```
for %%f in ("%d:\=" "%") do for /f %%n in ('echo %%f^|findstr /b /e /r "\"[0-9]*\""') do (
    echo %%~n
)
```

This script (based on: [How can I split a PDF's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/a/235401/1690543) and [Convert PDF 2 sides per page to 1 side per page](https://superuser.com/a/189109) and [How to set custom page size with Ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675371/how-to-set-custom-page-size-with-ghostscript)) splits the "booked" PDF into two sides. *THIS IS BEYOND THE SCOPE OF THE QUESTION, BUT ADDED FOR CONTINUITY AND CLARITY OF WHAT I'M DOING*

```
::Left Sections

gswin32c.exe ^
    -o left-sections.pdf ^
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
    -g5040x6120 ^
    -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" ^
    -f Test_PageNumbers.pdf -q

::Right Sections

gswin32c.exe ^
    -o right-sections.pdf ^
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
    -g5040x6120 ^
    -c "<</PageOffset [-504 0]>> setpagedevice" ^
    -f Test_PageNumbers.pdf -q
```

---

**Final Note**

*Once I have this final piece, I am good enough (I think) to compile one Batch program that processes a file and outputs a final PDF. I'm NOT(!) asking for an entire batch program from start to finish. This question is ONLY addressing the reordering of pages into one combined PDF where the pages are in order*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

2>nul del /q /f /a: "%~dp0OutPut.pdf"
set /a "_cnt=0, _pag=0" & set "_cat=" & set "_file="
set "_pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /on /b /a-d "%~dp0*-*.pdf"'
    )do for /f "tokens=2delims=: " %%p in ('""!_pdftk!" "%%~i" dump_data^|find "Pages:""'
    )do if "!_file!" == ""  (set "_file=%%~nxi")else (set "_pag=%%~p" & set "_file=!_file!,%%~nxi")

for /l %%L in (1,2,!_pag!)do if %%~L equ !_pag! (set "_cat=!_cat!R%%~L !_cat!L%%~L "
    )else set /a "_cnt=%%~L+1" && call set "_cat=!_cat!R%%~L L!_cnt! "
    
for /l %%L in (!_pag!,-2,1)do set /a "_cnt=%%~L-1" && call set "_cat=!_cat!R%%~L L!_cnt! "
cmd.exe /v /s /c ""!_pdftk!" R="!_file:*,=!" L="!_file:,%_file:*,=%=!" cat !_cat! OutPut "%~dp0OutPut.pdf""

endlocal
```

---

You may need more than one (or tow) for loop to do this.. d;)

---

> ***Final Note***
>
> *Once I have this final piece, I am good enough (I think) to compile >one Batch program that processes a file and outputs a final PDF. I'm >NOT(!) asking for an entire batch program from start to finish. This >question is ONLY addressing the reordering of pages into one >combined PDF where the pages are in order.*
>
> *Thank you!*
>
> - The batch below was created and used for the purpose of monitoring and testing the behavior of variables in and out of loops as well as the resulting file...

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

2>nul del /q /f /a: "%~dp0OutPut.pdf"
set /a "_cnt=0, _pag=0" & set "_cat=" & set "_file="
set "_pdftk=C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /on /b /a-d "%~dp0*-*.pdf"'
    )do for /f "tokens=2delims=: " %%p in ('""!_pdftk!" "%%~i" dump_data^|find "Pages:""'
    )do if "!_file!" == ""  (set "_file=%%~nxi")else (set "_pag=%%~p" & set "_file=!_file!,%%~nxi")

for /l %%L in (1,2,!_pag!)do if %%~L equ !_pag! (set "_cat=!_cat!R%%~L !_cat!L%%~L "
    )else set /a "_cnt=%%~L+1" && call set "_cat=!_cat!R%%~L L!_cnt! "
    
for /l %%L in (!_pag!,-2,1)do set /a "_cnt=%%~L-1" && call set "_cat=!_cat!R%%~L L!_cnt! "
cmd.exe /v /s /c ""!_pdftk!" R="!_file:*,=!" L="!_file:,%_file:*,=%=!" cat !_cat! OutPut "%~dp0OutPut.pdf""

echo\Your range pages: cat !_cat!
echo\Your cat command: pdftk R=input_#1.pdf L=input_#2.pdf cat ^^!_cat^^! OutPut.pdf & echo\
for /f tokens^=*useback %%i in (`type "%~0"^|findstr /l "!_cat!"`)do set /p "'=%%~i"<nul & echo\

endlocal

:: R1 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 1 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 01 :: 
:: L2 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 2 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 02 :: 
:: R3 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 3 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 03 :: 
:: L4 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 4 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 04 :: 
:: R5 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 5 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 05 :: 
:: L6 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 6 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 06 :: 
:: R7 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 7 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 07 :: 
:: L8 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 8 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 08 :: 
:: R8 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 8 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 09 :: 
:: L7 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 7 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 10 :: 
:: R6 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 6 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 11 :: 
:: L5 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 5 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 12 :: 
:: R4 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 4 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 13 :: 
:: L3 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 3 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 14 :: 
:: R2 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 2 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 15 :: 
:: L1 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 1 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 16 ::
```

- OutPuts

```bat
Your range pages: cat R1 L2 R3 L4 R5 L6 R7 L8 R8 L7 R6 L5 R4 L3 R2 L1
Your cat command: pdftk R=input_#1.pdf L=input_#2.pdf cat !_cat! OutPut.pdf

:: R1 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 1 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 01 ::
:: L2 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 2 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 02 ::
:: R3 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 3 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 03 ::
:: L4 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 4 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 04 ::
:: R5 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 5 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 05 ::
:: L6 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 6 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 06 ::
:: R7 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 7 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 07 ::
:: L8 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 8 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 08 ::
:: R8 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 8 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 09 ::
:: L7 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 7 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 10 ::
:: R6 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 6 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 11 ::
:: L5 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 5 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 12 ::
:: R4 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 4 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 13 ::
:: L3 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 3 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 14 ::
:: R2 <==> "Right-sections.pdf == Page 2 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 15 ::
:: L1 <==>  "Left-sections.pdf == Page 1 <==> OuPut.pdf Page 16 ::
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [`For /L /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)
- [`Finstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`Local Environment | Function`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [Variable and Substring Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [`If Condition() Else If Condition() Else()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Took me a moment to get this one going with the particular files/setup on my machine... but I did get it to work. So helpful, thank you!